# How to make frozen, fixed HTML content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I work on website where user creates some forms which would be filled by another users.

I have `dropdown` (image below) where user can choose what kind of input should be generated for another user:

[image]

> it is Georgian words and accordingly means **Text**, **Number**,
>   **Select (Yes-No)**, **Select**, **Big Text**, **File**, **Photo**

so I want to write on change event which draws for this user the form element which would be filled by another user. For example if user selects **Select (Yes-No)** [ასარჩევი (კი-არა)],

```
<select>
        <option>კი<option>
        <option>არა<option>
</select>
```

[image]

will be drawn. But this select should be frozen like an image. It is just for visualization for this user who creates the from to see how it would be shown for user who would fill it.

If I assume all this, how can I create some piece of html which would be fully disabled but it would not look like disabled.

How can I achieve this using *javascript-jquery*?

Comment: Do you just want them disabled?  Add the disabled attribute to your inputs if so <select disabled> ... </select>

Comment: no I want to be like an image, not disabled.

Comment: without or we can say disabled but It should not look like disabled

Comment: You could just disable the inputs and then use the css `:disabled` pseudo selector to make it look not disabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the css style `pointer-events: none` to any inputs you want to disable mouse interaction on.

CSS:

```
.display-only {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Html:

```
<select class="display-only">
        <option>კი<option>
        <option>არა<option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

`pointer-events` is only supported from IE11. It is a very good solution but if like me you need wider support, you could add a invisible div in front of your controls. Since this new div is not click-through, there is no interactions with the controls.

Although this would be doable through `:after` pseudo-element for your controls container, it would still cause problems in IE10.